# Conditional Forwarder being ignored

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, microsoft

It seems that DNS conditional forwarders are being ignored on a Windows 2012R2 server and I can't figure out what is going on exactly.

Situation as is explained:
There are two sites A + B with two domains X + Y.

Site A:
Domain X / Network: 192.168.1.0/24 
Two Windows Domain controllers/DNS Servers/DHCP Servers (W2016 Servers)
DNS Conditional forwarders to both DNS servers in Site B
Secondary dns prefix by GPO for resolving host names without the need for FQDN.

Site-To-Site VPN IPSEC connection in between.
Firewall: Public IP Site A is able to discover whole Site B
Firewall: Network Site A is able to discover whole site B
Firewall: Public IP Site B is able to discover whole Site A
Firewall: Network Site B is able to discover whole site A

Site B:
Domain Y / Network: 192.168.10.0/24
Two Windows Domain controllers/DNS Servers/DHCP Servers (1x W2012R2 & 1x W2016 servers)
DNS Conditional forwarders to both DNS servers in Site A
Secondary dns prefix by GPO for resolving host names without the need for FQDN.

On site A everything is working as expected. I can ping IP's, FQDN, hostnames and access all resources I want. Everything for domain Y is forwarded to the DNS servers in Site B and handeld correctly.

Now the problem is at site B, while all settings are exactly the same (checked this 5 times) only IP is working. So I can access everything on Site A by IP address but nothing else. Whatever I set for conditional forwarder it seems to be totally ignored. By pinging domain X, I get a public IP. When I remove the public dns record it just says that it cant find any host with that name. (Again, I can ping and RDP to the DC's at Site A).

I kinda tried all google search results (also from this forum) without luck. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Run nslookup in interactive mode with debug on a machine in Site B and query for a resource in Site A so you can see what is actually being queried and the structure of the query. I suspect a problem in your DNS client configuration or in your Conditional Forwarder configuration in Site B.

Comment: For me it looks still the same. Conditional Forwarders are being ignored. It checks servername.domain1.com then servername.domain2.com but for domain2(Site A) it goes external to ns1.metaregistrar. Everything that belongs to Site A domain just goes to public IP, so uses the public dns records and ignores conditional forwarder for that domain.